# Bootstrap - Customizing Cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm working on an app that uses the Bootstrap 4 Alpha. I'm trying to create some [cards](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/). I'm trying to recreate something that looks like a course card on [this site](https://teamtreehouse.com/library). But, I'm trying to use the default bootstrap styling. In other words, I'm trying to create a card that looks like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| [icon]                                          04.07.2016 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| intro                                                      |
| heading                                                    |
| a description that takes a couple of lines. It may         |
| have two or three lines of text and they'll wrap           |
| like this.                                                 |
|                                                            |
| [tag 1] [tag 2]                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've been experimenting with recreating this [here](http://www.bootply.com/hGaQd6w1EQ). The date isn't on the same line as the icon. My code looks like this:

```
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      <div class="text-xs-right">04.07.2016</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="text-muted">intro</div>
      <h4 class="card-title">Heading</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> a description that takes a couple of lines. It may have two or three lines of text and they'll wrap like this.</p>
      <ul class="list-inline text-muted">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> tag 1</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> tag 2</li>        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bootstrap 4 it would look like..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      <div class="pull-xs-right">04.07.2016</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="text-muted">intro</div>
      <h4 class="card-title">Heading</h4>
      <p class="card-text"> a description that takes a couple of lines. It may have two or three lines of text and they'll wrap like this.</p>
      <ul class="list-inline text-muted">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> tag 1</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> tag 2</li>        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/2EY9ZfMrdl

***EDIT*** - As of BS4 alpha 6, `pull-right` has changed to `float-right`.

Comment: I thought all of the `pull-right` stuff was deprecated in bootstrap 4? Or, is that responsive modifiers were just added?

Comment: It's in alpha so things may change, but `pull-*` is still there as of now: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#responsive-floats

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing. I was so close and beating my head on this :).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <div class="card-header clearfix">
      <i class="fa fa-circle pull-left"></i>
      <div class="text-xs-right pull-right">04.07.2016</div>
    </div>
```